# Words on a Subdivided Alphabet

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinatorics-on-words

Consider an alphabet of $N$ letters divided in $p$ families. The $i$-th family contains $n_i$ letters ($i=1,...,p$), and $\sum_{i=1}^p n_i = N$.

How many words of $q$ letters ($q \leq N$) use no letter more than once, and contain exactly $s$ pairs of adjacent letters from different families?

Comment: Crossposted from mathoverflow: http://mathoverflow.net/q/214461/1916

Comment: Goulden-Jackson is more useful for dealing with local conditions (like forbidden substrings). The no-letter-more-than-once thing is a global condition. Suggest counting partial permutations and using inclusion/exclusion to handle the conditions.

Comment: So you could use G-J with letter $a$ having weight $x_a$, with a ring structure in which $x_a^2=0$... Does that count?

Comment: It sounds clever but I'm not sure what you mean. How could I impose $x_a^2=0$?

Comment: Mathematically, you work in the quotient ring $\mathbb{Q}[x_a,\ldots]/I$ where $I$ is the ideal generated by $\{ x_a^2\mid a\in \mathcal A\}$ and $\mathcal A$ is your alphabet. The G-J generating function still makes sense here. Algorithmically you just compute as normal but any time you see $x_a^k$ with $k>1$ you treat it as zero.

Comment: I'm trying it, but the resulting formulas are pretty monstrous. How about the other method you suggested -- counting partial permutations? Could you explain how it applies? Sorry if I'm a bit slow.